# difficulties with video android programming (no image)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, mobile, galaxy-tab

I try to put a video on Galaxy Tab 2, however, the application starts but I have not the image, I have just the sound. So I tried to run the application on a mobile phone (Galaxy S2), and it works (sound + video) (my video is a mp4 with dimensions 1280x800).

**Code:**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    //VideoView view = new VideoView(this);
    VideoView view = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.view);
    //view.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    //setContentView(view);
    view.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://"+this.getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.video4));
    view.requestFocus();
    view.start();
    }
}
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<VideoView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/view"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_gravity="center">
</VideoView>
```

**Logcat:**

```
02-13 20:55:21.707: D/OpenGLRenderer(31903): Flushing caches (mode 1)
02-13 20:55:22.105: D/OpenGLRenderer(31903): Flushing caches (mode 0)
02-13 20:56:23.699: D/libEGL(31991): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
02-13 20:56:23.707: D/libEGL(31991): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
02-13 20:56:23.707: D/libEGL(31991): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
02-13 20:56:23.902: D/OpenGLRenderer(31991): Enabling debug mode 0
02-13 20:56:23.933: I/MediaPlayer(31991): path is null
02-13 20:56:24.050: W/MediaPlayer(31991): info/warning (901, 0)
02-13 20:56:24.199: I/MediaPlayer(31991): Info (901,0)
02-13 20:56:24.199: E/MediaPlayer(31991): mOnInfoListener is null. Failed to send MEDIA_INFO message.
02-13 20:56:24.207: D/MediaPlayer(31991): getMetadata
```

Here I tried to avi it was the same.

I changed the format of the video (I put flv), it works but I have again the problem in the logcat :

```
02-15 21:53:06.189: D/libEGL(15791): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
02-15 21:53:06.189: D/libEGL(15791): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
02-15 21:53:06.196: D/libEGL(15791): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
02-15 21:53:06.321: D/OpenGLRenderer(15791): Enabling debug mode 0
02-15 21:53:06.345: I/MediaPlayer(15791): path is null
02-15 21:53:06.689: D/MediaPlayer(15791): getMetadata
02-15 21:53:12.978: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(15791): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

Answer (score 0):

"Path is null" that is probably your problem, ensure the uri is correct. Also android.resource doesn't look or sound right... double check that.

### Update

Also you may want to wait for **prepare to be completed** before calling start:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#setOnPreparedListener(android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener)

### Update

Try this URI:

```
file:///android_asset/(filename.here)
```

Comment: I checked the uri it's correct, there is my video inside. For the android.resource, i don t know what else i can put. It s very weird because when i put my application on my cell phone it works and on the tablet there is just the sound...

Comment: Sounds like its not able to parse the video, not everything is supported. Checked the supported stuff for video's on android and see if it is supported.

Comment: I looked this link :http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html
So there is the mp4 for android.... and my cell phone is on android so i don t know what happen with my tablet?

Comment: 4.0.3 for the tablet and 4.0.4 for the phone

Comment: I think the problem is the resolution but the thing is that it s work on my little phone(with a little resolution) and not on the tablet (and i put exactly the same resolution of my tablet for the video).

Comment: i changed the format of the video (i put flv), it works but i have again the problem in the log cat :i changed the format of the video (i put flv), it works but i have again the problem in the logcat :
02-15 21:53:06.321: D/OpenGLRenderer(15791): Enabling debug mode 0
02-15 21:53:06.345: I/MediaPlayer(15791): path is null
02-15 21:53:06.689: D/MediaPlayer(15791): getMetadata
02-15 21:53:12.978: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(15791): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection

Comment: post your updates by refreshing your questing with an Update heading. Don't post code in comments.